# Convert Title Case Text to camelCaseText

Tags: javascript, regex, camelcasing, title-case

How would I convert `Hello World` to `helloWorld`?

Currently trying:

```
'Hello World'.replace(/\b ([A-Z]?)/g,  function(v) { console.log(v);return v.toLowerCase(); }) })
```

I.e., plan is to match 'word boundary, space, uppercase letter' and then replace with lowercase equivalent. The above has some bugs though...

Comment: @JackAllan is the reverse mode haha

Comment: Thanks - the first duplicate answer is correct. The second duplicate answer is another problem.

Comment: Yes, my pleasure to help you.

Comment: Just making the point that there should only be the first duplicate, the second one should be removed.

Comment: I can't remove the bad duplicate flag, the user that makes it should read better before flag posts.